Cartoon about a witch's Raven and Cat?
I was wondering if anyone may identify this cartoon I watched as a kid. Here are a few facts:
• I watched it as a kid in probably Cartoon Network around the early 2000's
• It was about this duo: A cat and a owl that belonged to a witch
• Every episode they would cast a terrible spell on their neighborhood by accident
• They always got the help of an ancient tree/turtle (not certain here) to solve the crisis
Thank you!

It might be Wunschpunsch. There's a raven, a turtle, a cat, and a witch.
Here is the plot, from Wikipedia.

In every episode, a wizard named Bubonic and his aunt, a witch named
  Tyrannia, must wreak havoc on the city in which they live or suffer a
  severe punishment from their supervisor, Maledictus T. Maggot. To be
  able to do so, they use an ancient magical parchment that, once
  utilized to activate a spell, said spell must be reversed within the
  next seven hours; otherwise, its effects will become permanent. To
  make sure the spells are reversed, Bubonic's and Tyrannia's pets,
  Mauricio the cat and Jacob the crow, must seek out Aunt Noah, an old
  turtle at the local zoo and head of the Animal Council, for a riddle
  on how to reverse the spell, which they usually manage to do in the
  nick of time. One of the episodes, Night of Wishes, is particularly
  inspired by the book. In that episode, the animals foil the spell by
  dropping a bell sound into the potion cauldron and Maledictus Maggot
  punishes Bubonic and Tyrannia for the foiled spell by attaching their
  homes, forcing them to live together. Unlike the other known
  punishments that never last enough to be seen in later episodes, this
  one seems to be permanent and has lasted at least five years (the
  animals recall it has been five years since it happened). Bubonic and
  Tyrannia are so clumsy that some of their spells bring trouble to
  themselves, and when the spells are undone, they feel a temporary
  relief that quickly ends when Maggot shows up to punish them for their
  failure.



That's it! Wow... I never thought I would find that! Hahahaha...

Yeah. It is an Raven, and I remembered them creating the caos. Apparently the witches did and they just fixed it.

Should I change the title and correct it to Raven so it isn't misleading?

I remember reading (English language) children's stories where the protagonist was Baba Yaga's cat.  It turns out that Baba Yaga was a very popular character in movies and TV according to this list.
http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0032258/1

Baba Yaga is an evil witch found in many Polish children stories. The most common premise is that if you quarrel with your parents and decide to leave home, you'll eventually end up lost in the woods—which is where the child-eating Baba Yaga dwells atop either a chicken's leg (pretty cool) or in a gingerbread house (pretty standard). She flies around in an iron "stupa" (a sort of urn or mortar), has a skeletal leg, and is usually accompanied by her cat, crow, owl, or snake. She's also blind (either completely or to some extent) but navigates unfailingly with her amazing sense of smell.

https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/european-parents-love-terrifying-kids-8762
Of course it is perfectly possible that the witch in that series was not Baba Yaga.

Is it Meg and Mog? Its a British series from 2003, shown on CITV, don't know if you are in the UK or US. But worth a shot 




I'm in Brazil, but it ain't this one. It had a more modern art style like other shows in Cartoon from 2000s.
